# ggplot data year over year - axis labels not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get data to plot year over year, exactly as is shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520639/ggplot-year-by-year-comparison). Unfortunately, it looks as though ggplot has changed since then, and the answer no longer works correctly.

If you try out the below code, you'll notice that the x axis labels no longer exist, compared to the image in the answer.

How can this answer be modified to show the abbreviated month names on the x axis?

```
library(ggplot2)
# Sample data
data <- read.table(text = "Month             Marg            Fiscal.Year
                           2009-01-01        20904494        2009
                           2009-02-01        30904494        2009
                           2009-03-01        40904494        2009
                           2009-04-01        30904494        2009
                           2009-05-01        43301981        2009
                           2009-06-01        14004552        2009
                           2009-07-01        24004552        2009
                           2009-08-01        34004552        2009
                           2009-09-01        44004552        2009
                           2009-10-01        54004552        2009
                           2009-11-01        64004552        2009
                           2009-12-01        44004552        2009
                           2012-02-01        58343271        2012
                           2012-03-01        68343271        2012
                           2012-04-01        58343271        2012
                           2012-05-01        58343271        2012
                           2012-06-01        38723765        2012
                           2012-07-01        77246753        2012",
                   header=TRUE, sep="", nrows=18)
data$MonthN <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(data$Month),"%m")) # Month's number
data$Month  <- months(as.Date(data$Month), abbreviate=TRUE) # Month's abbr.

g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = MonthN, y = Marg, group = Fiscal.Year, colour=Fiscal.Year)) + 
     geom_line() +
     geom_point() +
     scale_x_discrete(breaks = data$MonthN, labels = data$Month)
g
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The x-labels disappeared due to the use of `scale_x_discrete` instead of `scale_x_continuous`. But you don't need to do any transformation of the `Month` values outside of ggplot. Instead, you can use `Month` directly and transform it with the `lubridate` `month` function to get the month labels:

```
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data, aes(x=month(Month, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE), 
                 y=Marg, group=Fiscal.Year, colour=factor(Fiscal.Year))) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="", colour="Fiscal Year")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you explain 1) Why scale_x_discrete caused that? I would have thought individual months were discrete, and not continuous? 2) Where do you learn the nuances of ggplot? I've gone through some DataCamp tutorials, and googled, but am left with the feeling that most things are easy, but anything beyond that is cryptic.

Comment: (1) Your x variable (`MonthN`) is continuous (even though you set character labels, the underlying values are from a continuous variable). As a result, I would have thought using  `scale_x_discrete` would throw an error, rather than produce a plot without x breaks. In any case, in general, use `scale_*_continuous` when you have a continuous variable and `scale_*_discrete` for a discrete variable.

Comment: (2) hmm...I'm trying to think back to how I learned. When I first started using ggplot, I often referred to Winston Chang's [R Graphics Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023135.do), but with intervening updates to ggplot, it may be outdated. Probably better now to look at the new book [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), which is free on the web and co-authored by the author of ggplot2. Anyway, once I got the hang of the Grammar of Graphics, I mostly learned from Stack Overflow and from examples on various R blogs (see [R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/)).

Comment: @JohnTarr One thing that helps me a lot is to use ggThemeAssist addin. That allows you to set a lot of different aspects of the plot using a GUI.

Comment: All - thanks for the tips. I was thinking of MonthN as discrete, because it's integers, but the underlying data type is numeric, and therefore continuous. Also started to look at the R Graphics Cookbook, and then saw the publish date was prior to the big changes in ggplot2 v2. Will definitely check out ggThemeAssist. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = MonthN, y = Marg, group = Fiscal.Year, colour=Fiscal.Year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$MonthN, labels = data$Month)
g
```