# How to use individual days in year-on-year line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with the mean daily temperatures for an area beginning 1989. An extract of my dataset is:

```
         DATE   MAX   ATT TEMP
1  1989-01-04  33.8       26.2
2  1989-01-06  41.0       29.6
3  1989-01-09  43.5     * 38.5
4  1989-02-05  39.6     * 35.6
5  1989-02-25  41.0     * 36.1
6  1989-02-26  49.1       40.6
7  1989-03-04  60.4     * 57.9
8  1989-03-07  63.3       49.8
9  1989-03-09  64.4     * 54.0
10 1989-03-13  55.4     * 46.5
```

This dataset spans multiple year from 1989 to 2023. **I want to plot a line graph where every year is a line, with data from the TEMP variable.**

I can do this very easily with a data value for every month, by following solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520639/ggplot-year-by-year-comparison). However, this only creates lines of a monthly granularity, whereas I want every day in my dataset that has a value to be represented.

I initially tried this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

weather = read.csv("<FILE>")

weather$MonthN <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(weather$DATE_FORMAT),"%m")) # Month's number
weather$Month  <- months(as.Date(weather$DATE_FORMAT), abbreviate=TRUE) # Month's abbr.
weather$Year <- (format(as.Date(weather$DATE_FORMAT),"%Y")) # Year's number

ggplot(data = weather, aes(x = DATE, 
                            y = TEMP, group=Year, shape = Year, colour=Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Month", colour="Year") +
  theme_classic()
```

Unfortunately, this just creates a line graph with the entire dataset, with each year in a different colour (I want this, but for each year to be a line):

[image]

My initial idea was to make a value for every day of the year similarly to the month, but leap years and other things, as well as the fact that the recorded data entries are not uniformly spaced apart, means it did not work.

Here is my dataset:

https://pastebin.com/4hWTdsUB

Comment: If I understand the question then `geom_segment` might be a better strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to show various days-of-the-year by-year, then it can be done by converting all dates to "one year", keeping (of course) the real year and month for reference.

So we'll do these steps:

- convert to `Date`-class, and extract the `Year`;
- also create a `FakeDATE` that will have all of the correct days of the year but everything will be "one year". It's safer to pick a leap-year so we don't accidentally have `Feb-29` in there, I'll use `"2024"` here
- remove `shape=`, it's doing nothing here; if you want it, there are way too many years to use `shape=`, but ... good luck there
- add `scale_x_date` so that we can keep the x-axis from showing the year of our `FakeDate`
- (we don't actually need the `Month=` field, not calculated here)

```r
library(ggplot2)
weather |>
  transform(
    Year = gsub(".*([0-9]{4})$", "\\1", DATE),
    DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
    FakeDATE = as.Date(sub("[0-9]{4}$", "2024", DATE), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = FakeDATE, y = TEMP, group = Year, colour = Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Month", colour="Year") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]

---

Data was downloaded from your link, then read in here with no changes before the above code block.

```r
weather <- read.csv("~/Downloads/4hWTdsUB.txt")
```