# Graphics for data with a FakeDATE and one year highlighted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am preparing the chart according to the recipe provided by @r2evans:

[How to use individual days in year-on-year line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036816/how-to-use-individual-days-in-year-on-year-line-chart)

However, I would like the data for all years to be gray and for the selected year to be blue.
The number of years in the collection varies.

Comment: Sounds like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html might work

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the suggestion by jared mamrot is to add a column to the dataset that defines the year of interest and to plot two geoms.

Data preparation from [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78037040/2530121):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Read data previously downloaded from https://pastebin.com/4hWTdsUB#google_vignette
df <- read.csv("~/Downloads/4hWTdsUB.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Prepare data as per the linked answer you are replicating
df <- df %>%
  transform(
    Year = gsub(".*([0-9]{4})$", "\\1", DATE),
    DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
    FakeDATE = as.Date(sub("[0-9]{4}$", "2024", DATE), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Define year of interest and plot:

```
# Year of interest
yoi <- 1992

# Add new column to df to differentiate between year of interest and the rest
df <- df %>%
  mutate(colour = if_else(DATE >= paste0(yoi, "-01-01") & DATE <= paste0(yoi, "-12-31"), 
                          "blue", "grey")) # Can be any values, as long as they differ

# Plot data, one geom for all years and one geom for year of interest
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = FakeDATE, y = TEMP, group = Year, colour = colour)) +
  geom_line(data = filter(df, DATE >= paste0(yoi, "-01-01"), DATE <= paste0(yoi, "-12-31")),
            aes(x = FakeDATE, y = TEMP, group = Year),
            colour = "blue") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"),
                      labels = c(yoi, "All Other\nYears")) +
  labs(x = "Month", colour = "Year") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image: result]